# What proof of work style currency could early human civilizations develop?

Tags: humans, currency

The story I am writing centers on humanity with an alternate history but still close to ours. I am trying to come up with a proof of work style currency early human civilizations could have developed.

In such a currency, anyone can create new currency units, and there is no central authority regulating the supply. However, the process of producing new currency units is very difficult and laborious, and so people generally do not do it unless they are desperate for some money. The generally agreed value of a currency unit is more than its utility value but less than the cost of creating a new unit. In other aspects it is a regular currency.

What currency could meet these requirements?

Comment: What time period are you interested in? You are basically talking about bitcoin; but I imagine you want the concept to exist in an earlier time period.

Comment: **Why** would neolithic, copper, bronze or early iron-age civilizations develop proof-of-work currency, when what they **did** develop worked perfectly well?

Comment: You want a currency that isn't created or backed by a central authority, is equally obtainable by anyone so long as the same "work" is accomplished, you don't bother to tell us who/what/how different forms of work (e.g., entertainment vs. farming) are valued to ensure the same amount of "currency" is provided for that "work," and yet this valued interchange is used to buy and sell goods.  Have you studied economics?  What would your society do the first time someone decided their "work" was more valuable than their neighbor's?  What are you actually looking for?  Who sets the value?

Comment: A proof of work currency could originate from large things like grains being too cumbersome, and a lack of central authority to establish a fiat currency or no precious metals around to use. // Proof of work currency doesn't mean everyone makes new units as their job, only that anyone is capable of doing so if they really wanted to. Most people would just use the existing units and buy and sell like with others currencies.

Comment: @EPICI, Without a central authority (aka government) the value of work would soon be established by trade organizations who aggragate raw sources for distribution. In other words, a fiat currency is always the result of social evolution. Even bitcoin, were it ever adopted as a common currency, would quicky have its value set, not by the work needed to hash it, but by the trade value it represents in government-regulated markets. What is the proof of work for a guard? Peace?  What is a fair "work value" for taxation? Usury? Education? Service vs Production? Why are you asking this question?

Comment: Note: Proof of Work in cryptocurrnecies is not just "do a bunch of work, get a coin."  It's "do a bunch of work which is useful for making this currency function."

Comment: It's more like there's some manufactured object which is simple but very laborious to produce and has little to no utility value, and that's the currency unit. Anyone can make it if they really want, though most professions don't make it. The value of it stabilizes over time and it gets used as a regular currency. I agree a fiat currency may replace it in time, the concern then is if the proof of work currency can mature before then, and I think it is possible. I ask here because I'm having a hard time figuring out all the details on my own.

Comment: OK, we're getting closer to the issue (btw, to notify a user that you're responding to their post, use the @ symbol, as in @EPICI).  By "Proof of Work" what you really mean is "what can I use as a currency that's really hard to produce but could, nevertheless, be produced by anyone if they needed more cash?"  The idea being almost any effort involving negotiated value is better than taking the time to make the currency unless you're dead broke.  Right?  If so, you need to rewrite your question to make this clear (and it shorter in the process).  If not, more clarification needed.

Comment: Yes, that's it, creating new currency units is too bothersome for all but the desperate. Thanks for noting that, I'll go edit the question now.

Comment: I'm not really sure what it is you're asking for. When I think of a "proof of work" type currency, I think of "Ithaca Hours". This is clearly something that "early humans" don't need and would not have any use for. As it stands, barter is really the only answer for early people. If you *make* a coil of rope and trade it for a dozen eggs, well, neither of you can counterfeit rope or eggs, and both represent an agreed upon work-equivalence. What is a bronze age craftsman going to do with a piece of paper that says "1/2 Day Proof of Work" in exchange for a leather vest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof of work in cryptocurrencies is actually a fundamental aspect of how they work.  You don't just do work to get bitcoins. You do work *that furthers the stability of bitcoin for everyone*, and proof of that gets you bitcoins.

However, to your question:

> In such a currency, anyone can create new currency units
>
> The generally agreed value of a currency unit is more than its utility value but less than the cost of creating a new unit.

Combining these two, we see that if such a currency exists, there will be a caste of individuals whose time is worth more minting new currency than it is doing productive labor.  The larger the difference between the utility value of the physical currency objects and the value of the currency, the larger this caste will be.

The closest real-life example of this I can think of came from England, during the early days of the railroad.  There was no such thing as welfare back then.  You earned your keep.  One honest way to make a living for the poorest of the poor was to break rocks for the railroad.  Think of the image of prisoners being forced to break rocks -- that was actually a living.  You were paid by the pounds of rocks you could fit through a small hole.  The hole was graded such that the broken rocks were *perfect* to be used as track ballast under the railroad.  Those rocks were worth *value*, though admittedly not more than its utility cost.  One could have used them as currency, if it wasn't more convenient to get them turned into pounds and pence.

Another real life example might be the cocoa beans of the Incans.  Cocoa beans were cold hard currency for the Inca.  10 cacao beans were enough to buy one rabbit (also roughly the same price for a night with a prostitute. Very interesting culture they had...)  You could theoretically grow cacao with your time, so this could be close to the kind of currency you mention, though a professional gardener may make more than the average peasant, and you do need to have land to grow the cacao.

Answer (score 5):

## Barter

Any farmed or manufactured good is proof of work. You can't just find a bushel of wheat or a clay pot. The fact that you have this thing is proof that *someone* did the work necessary to grow or make the item in question.

What you are really looking for is proof-against-stealing. I may have grown a bushel of wheat, but that guy over there with a sword can take it from me; and then there is no way to prove that he didn't grow the wheat.

Ultimately, there will always be stealing, so I don't see a way that you can have what you are looking for. Even un-breakable cryptocurrencies can be stolen if you point a gun at the person who has them and make them transfer to you.

Comment: This is likely the only viable answer for an early civilization, but how do you value a guard's work? or a musician's? or a politician's?  How does a king/government establish taxes?  I wonder what the OP thinks "fair" means?

Comment: @JBH "*I wonder what the OP thinks "fair" means?*" Something feel-good, hand-wavy and completely divorced from reality.  The obvious answer to your earlier question "Have you studied economics?" is "no".

Answer (score 1):

If you form a ball out of clay, rub it with dust, rub it with finer dust, etc, you will get a mirror-finish sphere after a few days of work, not unlike billard balls. Clay is pretty much ubiquitous, and you only need that, and your hands, so the prerequisites are as low an entry barrier as you're likely to get. Clay balls are pretty rugged.

Work going into such an object can be arbitrarily high: if there is a convention that only three-colored spheres with specific patterns are eligible, days will turn into weeks.

One problem will stay: Any warlord can build pens where she imprisons captured servants ('server farms'/'blockchaingangs'), feeding them the scarce resources of the surrounds, thereby enriching herself at the expense of the many.

Answer (score 0):

As Kingledion mentioned, it would literally be a barter system. It feels like you are fishing for an answer based on cryptocurrencies but the biggest difference is that all the transactions and proofs of work are recorded which would be impossible for an early human civilization.

Here is just my explanation of why barter is literally what your describing. Lets say there are two towns. One mining town that produces Ore and One farming town that produces wheat. The value of wheat in the farming town is cheap. Everyone makes it and exchanges it for goods. Its value is low but its traded because everyone needs food. They barter with each other to find a suitable price both people think are worthwhile.

Now in this Farming village the price of ore is expensive. This is because they can't produce it locally. There is a lot of extra work put into getting it from the Mining Town and delivering it here. The Farming village needs ore, because they want reliable and long lasting tools so they can farm more efficiently and produce more wheat. A villager who goes to buy ore cheaply has to calculate the time taken to travel and production lost on the road. The exchange rate of the mining town (wheat to ore), the return journey and the extra effort to carry the ore back. When the ore arrives, the person who brought it over has put in work delivering it. They want wheat that would cover the cost, time spent and some extra due to their effort. A farmer agrees because they would basically lose the same amount of wheat if they went and got it themselves.

Now its a similar scenario in the mining town. Ore is abundant and cheap here because its what they produce. Everyone is a miner and gets ore at the end of the day. The problem they have is wheat. They don't produce any, and so rely on the farming village to supply them. There are two ways for this to happen. Either a miner walks to the farming village with wheat and exchanges it there for a high price, or a farmer brings wheat to the miner and the miner sells lower because he didn't need to put the extra effort in the travel and carry a block of ore with him.

In both cases, the cost of ore and wheat are representative of the amount of work put into it. There is the actual gathering and then the distribution of the material. It also reflects the availability of such materials and the demand for materials. If you want it to be more controlled, like crypto currency, you would simply need a trading authority at each town, which records the prices of goods and the latest/agreed exchange rate among the townspeople.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "set" value of a currency, not even with a modern government. Price controls are hard to enforce, and lead to black market with more realistic prices.

If effort to produce your currency item exceeds the value of the goods that could be bought with it, nobody will bother making the currency. They will make useful items, either for themselves, or to barter for whatever they need. This will make currency rare, and increase its trade value, which will in turn motivate people to make it.

So you essentially want a useless object to serve as currency, without government backing. This will have to rely on beliefs, at least initially. Perhaps people believe that making of the currency item transfers a portion of the maker's soul into it, bringing bad luck to the maker, and good luck to whoever owns the currency item. So now the item has value, even if it is all in the heads of the people. Once the currency is widely accepted, it will keep going even without the initial belief. The only that is inflation.

You need to ensure that nobody mass-produces the items. Maybe you can personalize items by including a fingerprint of the maker. More specifically, item is made of special resin/clay mix, that slowly solidifies only when it touches human skin, by dissolving that skin, or making it part of the item. So the only way to make a fingerprinted coin is to lose the skin from the tip of the finger. This way you have both limited production and verifiable source.

Comment: So... Human skin is involved in making something literally worth money. I can spot a gruesome loophole, right there.